# Validation Error in Wpf

Tags: wpf, validation, wpf-controls

How to check whether the text box has validation errrors in .cs file. I have attached validation rule for the textbox and i display the error message in the UI. Would i be able to check whether a textBox has validation error.

Edited :

I found the answer :

```
Validation.GetHasError(<textbox instance>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation.HasError attached property is there

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.haserror.aspx

```
bool hasError = Validation.GetHasError(txtAttributeName)
```

Comment: In the codebehind for a textbox instance say "txtAttributeName"